# python openpyxl read excel too slow

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsx, openpyxl

I have a .xlsx file, owning 1841 rows. Each row has 30 columns.Use openpyxl saving the whole info to a list.

```
def get_value(i,ws,article_row):
    value=ws.cell(row=article_row,column=i).value
    i+=1
    return value,i
def geneList(f):
    wb = load_workbook(filename=f, read_only=True)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    max_row = ws.max_row
    info_list=[]
    for ar_row in range(2,max_row+1):
        i=3#start from the 3rd column: sourceid 
        sourceID,i=get_value(i,ws,ar_row)
        pv,i=get_value(i,ws,ar_row)
        pubtype,i=get_value(i,ws,ar_row)
......
        item_dict={'sourceID':sourceID,'pv':pv,'pubtype':pubtype,
                   ...}
    info_list.append(item_dict)
```

But it takes around 20 mins to read all the information. I do not know how to solve this problem? It is to slow to parse the information. Convert .xlsx to .csv? Or use another tool to read?

Comment: Please post the full code but I suspect the problem is because you're not using the correct API for read-only files.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/antmomo/evan_test/blob/32dae4566daa13e9388527da1a84be96ab03499a/contribution_journal.py

Answer (score 6):

The problem is related to the extensive use of the `cell` method in read-only mode. In read-only mode openpyxl reads the relevant worksheet on-demand to reduce memory use low but means that for every lookup the XML will be parsed again. The code you have rewritten forces openpyxl to reparse the file for every cell in every row which is obviously slow. This is also entirely unnecessary because there is an API for row-based access. Just use `ws.iter_rows()` with the relevant delimiters to get cells you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is very fast to get the whole info by using ws.iter_rows(). But I am not clear the corresponding situation using data_only and read_only mode. When use the data_only, when use another ?

Comment: The documentation clearly explains the different parameters. It seems to me that you may be working without consulting the documentation.

Comment: read_only: optimised for reading, content cannot be edited;data_only controls whether cells with formulae have either the formula (default) or the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet.  Sorry I can not figure out why use data_only in my case by the official define.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with opening xlsx by openpyxl taking too much time.
I tried to remove all the data from the excel worksheet but it did not help too much. Seemingly empty excel file has had the size of about 500 kB.
I opened the xlsx file as a zip archive and found out that there is a "styles.xml" file inside being 7MB. I was not able to remove the styles from excel cells, so I just created a new workbook and copy/pasted all the contents from the original file.
It workes fine, takes little space and is being opened with openpyxl very quickly.
Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use xlwings. It's very fast and easy to use.

Comment: For beginning, you can install the Anaconda's package (search in google anaconda Python). This package have many modules (including xlwings). After, you can import it with: import xlwigns as xw. To connect to a book already open use xb = xw.book(), and finally I can use xw.Range("A1:B2").value to get the values in the range defined. Read the documentation for more information in the xlwigns website.