# Python pandas - loading workbook with lots of sheets issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a workbook that has 10 tabs. Two of these tabs contain raw data and rest of the tabs are charts with pivot tables. I am trying to update the two tabs with raw data with new data so in process of doing that I have to open and load the workbook into python. This takes over 10 minutes. 
Here is the code i have so far:

```
# loading weekly data into template
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('FRESH_DESK_METRICS_TEMPLATE.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('FRESH_DESK_METRICS_TEMPLATE.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
book.remove(book['WEEKLY_DATA_RAW'])
book.remove(book['ALL_DATA_RAW'])
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, "WEEKLY_DATA_RAW", index = False)
all_data_raw.to_excel(writer, "ALL_DATA_RAW", index = False)
writer.save()
```

If I load the data into simple spreadsheet where i have only two tabs with raw data, it works flawlessly and finish it in few seconds. However on this file where I have 10 tabs it takes 10 minutes because it is loading entire workbook with all sheets. 
Is there a way to accomplish this without having to load the workbook?

Comment: Have you looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756266/python-openpyxl-read-excel-too-slow)? You are also reading all of the sheets in the book during your `dict` conversion, which is likely the slow step. There's no need to write out the pivot table sheets again. You can initialize your `ExcelWriter` in `append` mode - see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html). Then you would only need to write out your new sheets.